# Can I POST to a new window that I want to open up?

Tags: html, redirects, drupal, post

Is this possible?

1. A third party site is running my Drupal module
2. An end user clicks on a link which will:
3. Open up a new window www.mysite.com/redirect.php
4. and POST certain data to this page www.mysite.com/redirect.php

I've seen the user's browser being redirected, but am not clear on how to do the above.

Comment: So... it's going to load redirect.php and then POST to itself? That all depends on what it is going to be POSTing, some more details about what you're trying to achieve might help.

Comment: I want it to open redirect.php in a new window and then POST it data...

Comment: What do you mean by "POST it data"? What data are you POSTing?

Comment: Do you just want a link that opens a POST-requested page in a new window (one request)? Or do you really want the page to open in a new window, and then a POST request to load in the same window (two requests)?

Comment: The second. I need to send a POST request to a page that I want to open in a new window.

Comment: It looks like one site can open another site in a new window, but it can't manipulate the other site once the window is open (*same-origin policy*). Is there some varying hidden form value on the page that you need to re-send in the POST request? If not, then perhaps the ideas in my answer below might work for you.

Comment: There are several ways around that, depending on what you're trying to do. But matt_tm seems set on not giving us any context for his question, such as what data he's posting/what his objective is, or why he needs a new window to do it.

Comment: @Bavi, @Lèse - This "above" is intended to be within a Drupal module and we want to present a button in it that when the user clicks on it, is redirected to ANOTHER website where he is automatically logged in. That second site is also ours and we're planning to have a "receiving" php script that verifies the request/IP/API-key and then "logs-in" the user and redirects him to the appropriate location based on the request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want a link that opens a POST-requested page in a new window here are some ideas. However, be aware a POST request can't be bookmarked.

- You can make a button that opens a POST-requested page in a new window.

  ```
  <form method="post" action="http://example.com/example.php"
    target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="value1">
  <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="value2">
  <input type="submit" value="Open results in a new window"> 
  </form>
  ```
- If you want it to look like a link, you can make a link with an onClick attribute that submits the form.

  ```
  <form name="myform" method="post" action="http://example.com/example.php"
    target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="value1">
  <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="value2">
  </form>

  <a href="http://example.com/example.php"
    onClick="document.forms['myform'].submit(); return false;">Open results
    in a new window</a>
  ```

  The onClick part submits the form, which opens the POST-requested page in a new window. The `return false` prevents the browser from also going to the href address in the current window at the same time. If Javascript is disabled or the link is bookmarked, the href address is used as a fallback, but the resulting page won't receive any POST values. This might be confusing or unfriendly for your users if they bookmark the link.

If you want the link to be bookmarkable, investigate if your page can accept GET parameters. If so, then you can make a bookmarkable link.

```
 <a href="http://example.com/example.php?name1=value1&name2=value2"
   target="_blank">Open results in a new window</a>
```

Comment: Hi - just checking, does your second code snippet open http://example.com/example.php in a new window and POST name1 and name2 to it?

Comment: @matt_tm I've been confused by your wording "open in a new window and POST to it". The first example above sends one POST request to the example.com server, the response of which the web browser displays in a new window. If Javascript is enabled, the second example does exactly the same thing as the first example, but looks like a link instead of a button. (When Javascript is enabled, the link's href is ignored, only the onClick is used. The `return false` tells the browser to ignore the href.)

Comment: What worked for me was placing the `target="_blank"` under the `<form>` element... instead of placing on the `<a>`....